# how to set up macro assembler in my simpleASM ide

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, sasm

im very new to assembly and i just recently downloaded sasm and
I'm trying to run this code.

```
; AddTwo.asm - adds two 32-bit integers
; Chapter 3 example

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096

.code
main PROC
mov eax, 5  ; move 5 to the eax register
add eax, 6  ; add 6 to the eax register

INVOKE ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

but the console says

Unable to start assembler. Check your settings.

Comment: From the SASM docs: _MASM assembler can not be included in the assembly because of its license. To use it, you should install MASM on your computer from site http://www.masm32.com/ and specify path to MASM assembler (ml.exe, path usually "C:/masm32/bin/ml.exe") and to MASM linker (link.exe, path usually "C:/masm32/bin/link.exe") in according fields on "Build" tab in settings._

Comment: Oh i see. thanks for the help!

Comment: @Michael Petch That link doesn't look very good to me. It's way out of date, pre 2000, I don't know why we would need to install a non-microsoft sdk here and I note that SASM doesn't even support x64.

Answer (score 1):

From the [SASM docs](https://github.com/Dman95/SASM/wiki/Help-(English)):

> MASM assembler can not be included in the assembly because of its
> license. To use it, you should install MASM on your computer from site
> http://www.masm32.com/ and specify path to MASM assembler (ml.exe,
> path usually "C:/masm32/bin/ml.exe") and to MASM linker (link.exe,
> path usually "C:/masm32/bin/link.exe") in according fields on "Build"
> tab in settings.

If you don't install the appropriate assembler for your platform you'll get the error you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after compiling assembly code with **SASM (SimpleASM) 3.11.1** on Linux Mint VERSION="20.2 (Uma).

> Unable to start assembler. Check your settings.

I resolve this issue with executing the next commands:

1. sudo apt install nasm
2. sudo apt install gcc-multilib

Comment: Same error message, but this question is about using MASM (on Windows), not NASM.  The source code in the question is MASM syntax.  If there's a SASM question about setting it up on Ubuntu, that would be a better place to post this answer.

Comment: I'm a also new in assembly. You are right. Question is about windows os. But ı got the same error message on linux os. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: If there's another Q&A with the same error message, but about Linux, then yeah repost there and delete this.  Otherwise it's probably not doing any harm, and people in the same situation as you (using Linux but google sent them here) might also end up here.